# jquery mobile login submit not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

My jquery mobile login submit not working

my jquery code is below...here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dD6Dg/

```
$('#loginform').submit(function (e) {
     alert("loggg");
     e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: '/class/login.php',
         data: $(this).serialize(),
         success: function (data) {
             if (data === 'Login') {
                 window.location = '/user-page.php';
             }
             else {
                 alert('Invalid Credentials');
             }
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: "not working" ? Did you try to debug ? To see what happens to the query ? Start by learning to use some web dev tools : https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Comment: no errorrs in console too

Comment: have you tried removing the beginning `front-slash` of the url. Give it a go .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `click` event instead of `submit`, because there is no submit button in your code. You are using `a` tag for it, for that you need to use `click` event not `submit`

```
$('#loginform').click(function(e) {
alert("loggg");
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: '/class/login.php',
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function(data)
       {
          if (data === 'Login') {
            window.location = '/user-page.php';
          }
          else {
            alert('Invalid Credentials');
          }
       }
   });
 });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/dD6Dg/2/)

Comment: Yes, or add a submit button

Comment: @MauricePerry yes you are right sir, or trigger submit event

Comment: thats working thanks :) how can i check if login and password field is empty ? any shortcuts ? or i should check if selector is empty ?

Comment: `if($('username').val()=='')` to check username